# 2 Mysql query for number of rows and main query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find a solution to have total rows affected of a query without the "limit" clause and the records of the query with limit clause... How to do that without 2 queries (count(*) and main query?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is my query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN abos a
ON p.userid = a.blogid OR p.userid = 11
LEFT JOIN posts_denied r
ON r.post_id = p.id AND r.userid = 11
WHERE (a.userid = 11 OR p.userid = 11)
  AND r.post_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mysql_affected_rows` like

```
mysql_query($sql_query);
echo "Number of rows effected = ".mysql_affected_rows();
```

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

And try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

Comment: I use mysqli, but mysql_affected_rows will take limit clause into consideration. I need without the limit clause

Comment: Please, do NOT use mysql_* functions in your posts in code since they are officially deprecated. use mysqli_* or PDO instead. Also you need to provide  numbers - either count with limit and without.

Comment: Here is my query: `SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN abos a
ON p.userid = a.blogid OR p.userid = 11
LEFT JOIN posts_denied r
ON r.post_id = p.id AND r.userid = 11
WHERE (a.userid = 11 OR p.userid = 11)
  AND r.post_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 5`